# how to submit form this Onchange? reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

how to submit form this Onchange? I don't have a button to fire the form, how to do that? I can't insert routes as it's a component for several clients. I use react hook forms

```
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        const avatar = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
        setAvatar(avatar)
      };
```

Comment: What form? can you add the complete component?

Comment: my form is an isolated component, all inputs and buttons are controlled components

Comment: Can you post your code within the component, so we can see what you're struggling with? [Check this out for a template](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this solution using useEffect

```js
const [avatar,setAvatar] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
if(avatar) handleSubmit();
}, [avatar]);

const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        const avatar = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
        setAvatar(avatar)
      };

// suppose that this is this is your handleSubmit function 
const handleSubmit = () => {
        // your code goes here
      };
```